ESP32 rebooting after trying to write memory mapped flash
I succesfully create a partition in flash like so (partitions.csv):
# Name,   Type, SubType, Offset,  Size, Flags
nvs,      data, nvs,     36K,     20K,
factory,  app,  factory, 64K,     2M,
storage,   data, spiffs,  ,        5M,

I load the partition with the following code:
    Serial.println("Acquire partition");
    const esp_partition_t *partition = esp_partition_find_first(
      ESP_PARTITION_TYPE_DATA,     // Type of partition
      ESP_PARTITION_SUBTYPE_ANY,   // Subtype
      "storage"                    // Label of the partition
    );

    if (partition == NULL) {
      Serial.println("Partition not found");
      return false;
    }

    Serial.println("Map partition");
    const void *mapped_memory;
    spi_flash_mmap_handle_t mmap_handle;
    esp_err_t err = esp_partition_mmap(
      partition,
      0,                  // Offset within the partition
      partition->size,    // Size of the mapping
      ESP_PARTITION_MMAP_DATA,
      &mapped_memory,     // Pointer to mapped memory
      &mmap_handle        // Handle to unmap later
    );

    if (err != ESP_OK) {
      Serial.printf("Failed to mmap flash memory: %s\n", esp_err_to_name(err));
      return false;
    }

Up to here everything goes fine and nothing fails. I seem to get a mapping of flash to memory. But then, I try to copy a buffer of data to this region (I checked that the size of the partition is greater than the size of the data I need to copy):
uint8_t *flash_buffer = (uint8_t *) mapped_memory;
Serial.printf("Copying... %p %d", flash_buffer, model_data_size);
for (int i = 0; i < model_data_size; i++) {
  flash_buffer[i] = model_data[i];
  if (i % 10000 == 0) {
    Serial.printf("%d\n", i);
  }
}
Serial.println("\nCopied");

As you can see, to debug I print every 10000 bytes written. When running the program, it runs fine for the first 10000 copied bytes and then the system reboots with the following error:
rst:0x8 (TG1WDT_SYS_RST),boot:0xa (SPI_FAST_FLASH_BOOT)
Saved PC:0x420219ff
SPIWP:0xee
mode:DIO, clock div:1
load:0x3fce3818,len:0xf88
load:0x403c9700,len:0x4
load:0x403c9704,len:0xa14
load:0x403cc700,len:0x2d64
entry 0x403c988c
E (312) esp_core_dump_flash: No core dump partition found!
E (312) esp_core_dump_flash: No core dump partition found!

I tried changhing the flash mode from QIO to DIO but nothing changed. My question is: what is causing this? How can I mitigate it? I'm in dire need for help, any help is appreciated, thank you!

Are you trying to write data into Flash? That is not as simple as assigning a value to an address in memory-mapped space. If you wish to write raw data info Flash then it's esp_partition_erase_range() to erase and esp_partition_write() to write. If you're trying to use this as an SPIFFS file system, then you need to mount the file system and then use the standard file system API to access it.

Thank you so much! I didn't know this, it fixed my issue
